# Remove the first element (key and value) from an array, turning it into another array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to capture the first element of an array and its value in a second array, removing it from the first.

Is there a core PHP function that does what `my_function` does here?

```
function my_function(&$array) {
  $key = current(array_keys($array));
  $value = $array[$key];
  unset($array[$key]);
  return [$key => $value];
}
$array = [
  'color' => 'red',
  'car' => 'ford'
  'house' => 'cottage',
];

$top = my_function($array);

print_r($top);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [color] => red
)
Array
(
    [car] => ford
    [house] => cottage
)
```

If there's not a core function, is there a simpler way of achieving this behavior? IIRC, passing variables by reference is frowned upon.

Bonus question: is there a word for the combination of both key and element from an array? I feel like 'element' doesn't necessarily include the key.

**edit** Since there seems to be a commonly held misunderstanding, at least in PHP 7, `array_shift` does *not* do the desired behavior. It only returns the first value, not the first element:

```
$ cat first_element.php
<?php

$array = [
  'color' => 'red',
  'car' => 'ford',
  'house' => 'cottage',
];

$top = array_shift($array);

print_r($top);
print_r($array);

$ php first_element.php
redArray
(
    [car] => ford
    [house] => cottage
)
```

Comment: you wrote *in a second array* - where is it in your code?

Comment: Array "elements" consist of "keys" and "values," so yes, elements are the right word. I think you're replacing "value" with "element."

Comment: [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry my question was confusing, I've updated the code. `$top` means "the top (or first) element from the original array". It becomes an array from the function's return: `return [$key => $value];`

Comment: @ishegg `array_shift` returns only the value; it doesn't preserve the key.

Comment: @user151841 you’re completely right, hadn’t noticed... Never had the need I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_splice` doesn't always preserve keys, so just get the key and combine with the result of `array_shift` to also remove it:

```
$result = [key($array) => array_shift($array)];
```

If needed, reset the array pointer:

```
reset($array) && $result = [key($array) => array_shift($array)];
```

Comment: This preserves numeric keys, so it works for both associate arrays and regular.

Comment: Careful with this too, `key()` uses the current array position. If you, for example, use `foreach()` to change the values (it can be *anything* that moves the pointer), you'll get incorrect results. Use `reset($array)` before to guarantee results. See [here](https://3v4l.org/KLcvr) (works correctly for PHP7+, `key()` uses the array by value since that version)

Comment: Yes, if you are operating on the array then `reset` before.

Comment: I'm trying to think if this concern would actually play out in development. pulling the first element off of an array when you were in a foreach loop on that array would really be expressing you wanted the *next* element in that array, after the one the pointer was currently on? Or, if you were already in a loop and past the first element, you already had a chance to capture that key an value... you would be saying "give me the first element, and while you're at it, just get rid of it, too" ... Kind of thinking out loud here I guess.

Comment: @user151841 You have a point. I think, though, if I were doing this I'd definitely have the first instructions in another function (reusability and all). A separation of concerns kind of things. So I'd modify the values in the array first, and then do the logic you're trying to do. The solution works like you wanted, just have that little "but" in mind :).

Answer (score 3):

Try this ([array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)):

```
$top = array_splice($array, 0, 1);
```

The `$top` will contain the first element and the `$array` will contain the rest of the elements.

Comment: For the record, this won't keep the key if it's a number (including a string containing a number): see [here](https://3v4l.org/S8IOV)

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_function($array) {
    $first_key = key($array);
    return array($first_key =>$array[$first_key] );
} 
$array = array(  'color' => 'red', 'car' => 'ford','house' => 'cottage' );

$first = my_function($array);
array_shift($array);print_r($first);print_r($array);
```

Comment: Might add some text/explanation or something.

Answer (score 0):

I made this function:

```
function array_extract(array &$array, $num) {
  $output = array_slice($array,0, $num);
  array_splice($array,0, $num);
  return $output;
}
```

Here's what it does

```
$ cat test.php
<?php

$test = [234,25,45,78,56];

echo "test:\n";
print_r($test);

while( count($test) ) {
  echo "extraction:\n";
  print_r(array_extract($test, 2));

  echo "\ntest:\n";
  print_r($test);
}

$ php test.php
test:
Array
(
    [0] => 234
    [1] => 25
    [2] => 45
    [3] => 78
    [4] => 56
)
extraction:
Array
(
    [0] => 234
    [1] => 25
)

test:
Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => 78
    [2] => 56
)
extraction:
Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => 78
)

test:
Array
(
    [0] => 56
)
extraction:
Array
(
    [0] => 56
)

test:
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Quite simple:

```
$array1 = [
  'color' => 'red',
  'car' => 'ford'
  'house' => 'cottage',
];
$array2 = array_unshift($array1);

--> result
$array2 = [
   'color' => 'red'
];

$array1 = [
  'car' => 'ford'
  'house' => 'cottage',
];
```

Comment: Have you run this code? On my system, with PHP 7.1.7, `array_shift()` returns only `red`.

Comment: Check the manual for [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).

Comment: _Warning: array_unshift() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given_